# Create dual graph with street continuity

Tags: networkx, openstreetmap, graph-theory, osmnx

I want to recreate steps taken in the paper [Networks and Cities: An Information Perspective](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0407054.pdf). Graphs traditionally represents streets as edges, but in this paper, a different approach is used

> In network language, your trajectory can be mapped to a path in an “information city
> network”, where roads map to nodes and intersections between roads map to links between the nodes.

The graph in description is also called a Dual Graph (which comes from a Planar Graph).

There are functions that translate Planar Graphs into Dual ones, but they do not consider street continuity. It is possible to see the difference between an algorithm that does not consider continuity (first one) to one that consider. If two nodes represents the same street, they should be only one node.

[Planar to Dual Graph Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpPYo.png)

[Planar to Dual Graph Conversion with continuity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAeef.png)

How can I generate Dual NetworkX graphs with Street Continuity?

Obs.: I use OSMNX to generate graphs, but I could also use Momepy, if easier.

Comment: The OSMnx examples gallery demonstrates how to convert a graph to the dual graph (aka, the line graph): https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v1.5.0/notebooks/00-osmnx-features-demo.ipynb

Comment: @gboeing the notebook conversion uses `networkx.line_graph()`, which does not consider Street Continuity

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and iterated over the nodes with this function. Where gdf is a geopandas dataframe with the street names and the shape.

```
def polystring_dual_approach(node):
    line = gdf[gdf['street_name'] == node]['linestring'].values[0]
    new_nodes=gdf.loc[gdf['linestring'].touches(line,align=True)]['street_name']
    new_nodes=list(new_nodes)
    edges_to_add = [(node, new_node) for new_node in new_nodes]
    G.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)
```